# Clarifying Google Plus API Quotas

Tags: google-plus, quotas

The [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) distinguishes between `Google+ API` and `Google+ API (Sign-in)`. What's the precise distinction here, i.e., what specific calls does the latter refer to?

(The sign-in quota is showing up as many per second per user, which would seem excessive if it really is just a single user signing in. I guess it's an arbitrary value.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods that require authorization of the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope fall into the "Google+ API (Sign-In)" quota. All other Google+ methods fall under the "Google+ API" quota.

"Google+ API ("Sign-In") quota covers these methods:

- people.list
- people.get
- moments.insert
- moments.remove
- moments.list

Google+ API quota:
 - All other methods

[Documentation info on quotas](https://developers.google.com/+/api/#quota)

Comment: Hey. I am sending now all the request using Google+ API quota without Sign-In. And its limit is pretty small. I'm using the service with my developer key: `service = apiclient.discovery.build(service_name, service_version, developerKey=api_key)`. I didn't get what should I do to use the sign-in version of quota. I am following pages and fetching comments, +1s and resharers. I'd like to use sign-in quota for +1s and resharers (people.list API call).